# using requests module to access api

Tags: python, python-3.x

The curl command works as expected. But similar python code does not.

```
# curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"img_url":"http://tleyden-misc.s3.amazonaws.com/blog_images/ocr_test.pnge","engine":"tesseract"}' http://35.154.148.131:9292/ocr
```

Expected output:

```
You can create local variables for the pipelines within the template by
prefixing the variable name with a "$" sign. Variable names have to be
composed of alphanumeric characters and the underscore. In the example
below I have used a few variations that work for variable names.
```

I tried this python code:

```
import requests
url = 'http://35.154.148.131:9292'
data = {"img_url":"http://tleyden-misc.s3.amazonaws.com/blog_images/ocr_test.png","engine":"tesseract"}  
r = requests.post( url, json={'json_payload': data})
```

This returns the following error:

```
b'<h1>OpenOCR is running!<h1> Need <a href="http://www.openocr.net">docs</a>?'
```

How do I post the dictionary using data parameter?

Comment: How about calling just `r = requests.post( url, json=data)`? According to [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) that's the way to use it. Also, in your Python code, you are missing the `/ocr` endpoint in the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests 
url = 'http://35.154.148.131:9292/ocr'
data = {"img_url":"http://tleyden-misc.s3.amazonaws.com/blog_images/ocr_test.png","engine":"tesseract"}
r = requests.get(url, json=data) 
r.text
```

Result

```
u'You can create local variables for the pipelines within the template by\nprefixing the variable name with a "$" sign. Variable names have to be\ncomposed of alphanumeric characters and the underscore. In the example\nbelow I have used a few variations that work for variable names.\n\n'
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I managed to do this:

```
import requests
url = 'http://35.154.148.131:9292/ocr'
data = {"img_url":"http://tleyden-misc.s3.amazonaws.com/blog_images/ocr_test.png","engine":"tesseract"}  

r = requests.post( url, json=data )
```